# Cannot get if to evaluate the result of $? correctly

Tags: bash, grep

So here's what I'm trying to do. I want to grep through a file for two strings and then print out to the user whether the strings are present.

```
grep rn.jar $start_catalina #2&>1
echo $? #2&>1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "RN_JAR variable set correctly."
else printf "%s\n" "RN_JAR variabe not correctly set. Please set it."
      fi

grep $\RN_JAR $start_catalina 2&>1
echo $? 2&>1
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
printf "%s\n" "RN_JAR variable set correctly."
else printf "%s\n" "RN_JAR variable not set correctly."

fi
```

I thought I had this working but then I realized that the second test was *always* evaluating true.  At one point I had all of the above flowing together in one big if construction but I could never get the second statement to evaluate as false. I broke them out into two separate statements and now neither evaluates as false (in other words, if I pull the strings out of catalina.sh even though the return is 1 it still prints the statement as if it were true). In pulling them apart I managed, somehow, to break both.

I know that it's ugly and that there's a simpler way to accomplish this but right now, I'm just having a blind spot as to why I cannot get these strings to evaluate as false.  I'm sure I'm doing something obvious that I just can't see but for the life of me, I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo $? #2&>1` will reset the value of `$?`

You need

```
grep rn.jar $start_catalina #2&>1
exitval=$?
echo $exitval #2&>1
if [ $exitval -eq 0 ]; then
  printf "%s\n" "RN_JAR variable set correctly."
else
  printf "%s\n" "RN_JAR variabe not correctly set. Please set it."
fi

grep $\RN_JAR $start_catalina 2&>1
exitval=$?
echo $exitval 2&>1
if [ $exitval = 0 ]; then # this should not work as it evaluates as string comparison
  printf "%s\n" "RN_JAR variable set correctly."
else
  printf "%s\n" "RN_JAR variable not set correctly."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked a treat!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than:

1. Running `grep` and discarding it's output and
2. Evaluating `$?` later

You can use `grep -q` like this:

```
if grep -Fq "rn.jar" $start_catalina; then
   printf "%s\n" "RN_JAR variable set correctly."
else
   printf "%s\n" "RN_JAR variabe not correctly set. Please set it."
fi
```

As per `man grep`:

```
-q, --quiet, --silent
```

> Quiet mode: suppress normal output.  grep will only search a file until a match has been found, making searches
>                potentially less expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `$?` give you the exit value of the last command.  In the case of both `if` tests in your script, this will be the immediately previous `echo` command (NOT the grep), which should always succeed...

Answer (score 0):

When you do `echo $?` you are printing the result of the last command, but destroying it, because just after that, `$?` will be the result of `echo`, not the previous command. And `echo` will likely succeed.

The solution is to use a variable:

```
RES=$?
echo $RES
if [ $RES -eq 0 ]; then
...
```